# Get the endpoint results of all nodes in a cluster

Tags: rest, service, kubernetes, endpoint

I am using Kubernetes service to send certain data say, the list of fuse mount points of each worker. When I call the REST  API , the service will list the endpoint details of a particular worker node. Is there any way I can get the details of all the worker nodes in one single service endpoint.

```
router.GET("/get", GetMountResult)
```

The above code post the result to a particular endpoint using below code

```
   go func() {
    fmt.Println("API Call")
    router.Run(":" + port)
}()
```

In `GetMountResult` I just put the final result

```
filelogger.Info("List of mount points:", zap.Any(" ", finalmap))
c.JSON(200, finalmap)
```

Comment: Without knowing details of how you are getting details for one node, it is impossible to imagine the answer. Can you explain please?

Comment: @VishalBiyani I have added the details now. Hope this is sufficient .

Comment: Kubernetes is not supporting it out-of-the-box by default.
I see you are a golang user. Please try to run a dedicated container to gather mount points  from neighborhoods and prepare an aggregate output and API to return results. What do you think about it?

Comment: Maybe sensu fits you need? It is aggregating server for informational checks and include API references https://docs.sensu.io/sensu-core/1.0/reference/server/